# How to set the titlebar in every activity programmatically?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the titlebar in every activity programmatiaclly from one particular activity?

I can set the titlebar of a particular activity programmatically from within that activity, but subsequent activities have the string set from the manifest thereafter.

To set a title I use the following from within the activity. I would like every activity set like this in the application.

```
setTitle(carerName + " is now logged in");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write base activity and call a method of super .

```
public class DerivedActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...}
    }

public class DerivedActivity2 extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     ...}
    }

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTitle(carerName + " is now logged in");
   }
   }
```

Comment: hi, does this mean i have to change every activity in the application to extend baseActivity? there's maybe 100 different activities.

Comment: Yes, it means. Moreover, you had to do it in the very beginning of the project